# Send a chain to the concatenated gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Currently I'm sending wanting to send these two variables `HOST WS` and `PORT WS`, I've already captured them in the view, but the conflict is that those two chains I want to send them and at the same time concatenate them within the Gradle, exactly in the URL parameter .

**The purpose of this is to make my web-service completely configurable when I change my route.**

Do you have any idea how to do it? I would like a hand.

Here I configure these two parameters
[image]

I want to send it concatenated to my Gradle
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
To use buildconfig from build.gradle to Android manifest then.
android {
  // For settings specific to a product flavor, configure these properties
  // for each flavor in the productFlavors block.
  defaultConfig {
    // Creates a property for the FileProvider authority.
    def filesAuthorityValue = applicationId + ".files"
    // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
    manifestPlaceholders =
      [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue]
      // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
      buildConfigField("String",
                       "FILES_AUTHORITY",
                       "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\"")
  }
  ...
}
...

<manifest>
  ...
  <application>
    ...
    <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${filesAuthority}"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      ...
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```